# How to push html tag into stack in Java?

Tags: java, html, stack

I am attempting to read from an HTML.txt file and push the tags into a stack to be used later. The code builds and executes, but the count of my open/close tags is always 0 and I am unsure why. I have tried/read everything under the sun, and I am only posting this because I have no clue where else to turn. Please understand.

The first line of the file I am attempting to read is:

```
<html lang="en" style="">
```

Here is my code as I have it so far:

```
public boolean validateTags() throws FileNotFoundException {
        String oneLine = "";
        String tag = "";
        int space, closeTag;
        Scanner file = new Scanner(filename).useDelimiter("<");             //** ATTEMPT 1 **
        space = oneLine.indexOf(' ');
        int openBracket = oneLine.indexOf('<');
        oneLine = file.next();

        while (file.hasNext()) {
            if (oneLine.startsWith("<") && oneLine.endsWith(">") && !oneLine.startsWith("<!")) {
                tag = oneLine.substring(openBracket, space);

                openTags.push(tag);
            }
            if (oneLine.startsWith("<") && oneLine.endsWith("/>")&& !oneLine.startsWith("<!")) {
                tag = oneLine.substring(openBracket,space);


                closeTags.push(tag);
            }
            if (!oneLine.startsWith("<") || !oneLine.endsWith(">")) {
                throw new InvalidHTMLException();
            }
        }
```

As per suggestion, I tried to change my Scanner from its original code to Scanner file = new Scanner(new File(filename)); and it throws my exception in my final if-statement, to avoid any unnecessary confusion for future suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

`Scanner file = new Scanner(filename).useDelimiter("<");` means you will never see a token with `<`. Remove the `.useDelimiter("<")` Second `Scanner(String)` will only scan the `String`. So change it to

```
Scanner file = new Scanner(new File(filename));
```

Comment: I made these changes and it throws my InvalidHTMLException.

Comment: Perhaps you should remove `throw new InvalidHTMLException();` since `<p>Your logic isn't correct</p>` is valid HTML.

Comment: I can't remove the exception. I need it to ensure the rest of my code runs correctly :/ Thank you for your help though.